# Nightwatch JS reach a specific web element from a web element list

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a list of webElements and I want to access a specific webElement. For this example the first will be enough.

I'm using Nightwatch JS with mocha and ES6.

```
it('Should do something', (client) => {
  client.api.elements('css selector', '.InstanceDetail__header', (items) => {
    console.log(items.value);
  });
});
```

This log a list of web elements. How can I access the first element?

I tried using elementIdText:

```
instead of console.log(items.value);
client.elementIdText(items[0].ELEMENT, (result) => {
  console.log(result.value);
});
```

But it simply doesn't return anything.

What is the correct way to access a web element inside a web elements list?

Comment: does `console.log(items[0].value);` not give you what you need?

Comment: @Craicerjack well on `console.log(items[0]);` it returns undefined and on `console.log(items[0].value);` it fails without showing the log.

Comment: what does `items` look like - can you post output of `console.log(items)` - or a sample of it?

Comment: @Craicerjack here are the output I get:
`console.log(items);` returns {sessionId: 'id number', status: 0. state: 'success', value: [{ELEMENT: '1'}, {ELEMENT: '2'}, {ELEMENT: '3'}], class:'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response', hCode: numbers}